# iText: custom left and right margins for header

Tags: pdf, layout, itext, margins

I created a java class that creates a pdf document. This document has a header composed by a table with text and images, which is present on every page.

I put the header with `PdfPageEventHelper.onStartPage()` and the code is as follows:

```
Document doc = new Document();
ByteArrayOutputStream baos= new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, baos);
doc.setMargins(Utilities.millimetersToPoints(30), Utilities.millimetersToPoints(20),   Utilities.millimetersToPoints(10), Utilities.millimetersToPoints(15));
writer.setPageEvent(new HeaderFooter(Variables...));
doc.open();

... do other stuffs...
```

I have the following problem: I would like to have different left and right margins for the header respect to the rest of the document: in particoular the header table should have the left side more on left respect to the body.

It it possibile to do this? Is there a simple solution for my problem? I read the documentation but I can't find the simplest solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: i putted the header in a Paragraph and set the left margin negative... 
brutal but effective :)

Comment: @Joce While not a very elaborate one, Alessandro's answer is an answer seemingly solving his question, not merely a comment, critique, or request for clarification. Asking for a working sample might be appropriate, though.

Comment: This is my answer for the problem, not request for clarification.

Comment: Ugly, but works! (8 years later lol)

Answer (score 1):

If you implemented your `HeaderFooter` class in the same way as this [example](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=104), you just have to set the desired values in the [`writeSelectedRows()`](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfPTable.html#writeSelectedRows%28int,%20int,%20float,%20float,%20com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte%29) call you see in `TableFooter#onEndPage()` to put your header at an absolute position.

Comment: This is the better answer. It seems that the *solution* provided by the author of the question uses `document.add()` in the `onStartPage()` method. That's a bad idea. It can cause side-effects that are undesirable.